# Cannot get mouseover to work, don't understand JavaScript well enough

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have looked on Google, and everywhere in the forums. Just learning JavaScript, so any help is appreciated. When I put .wav in the parameters it says error, don't know if that makes a difference anyway.

In the head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function playSound(cellowav) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
       "<embeded src=\""+cellowav.wav+"\" hidden=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />
  }
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
<p onmouseover="playsound('cellowav.wav');">
  <img src="smiley.png" border="0" alt="smiley" />
</p>
```

Okay, I found that yes the cellowav doesn't belong in the parameter, or the string and the sound will play automatically with the embed tag in html. I was missing the closing -"- in the string fixed that. Changed the functions parameters from (cellowav) to (soundfile) and in the string + cellowav + to

- soundfile +.

  ```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function playSound(soundfile) {
   document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
   "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\"
   loop=\"false\" />";
   }
   </script>


   <span id="dummy"></span>
   <p onmouseover="playSound('cellowav.wav');"><img src="smiley.png"  
   alt="smiley"></p>
  ```

Comment: Well `embeded src` should be `embedded src`, for one.

Comment: You're currently getting `<embeded src="cellowav.wav.wav" ... />` or rather, you're not: I don't thing variables can contain dots.

Comment: Not to be rude, but if a website randomly plays a sound without visible cause, I close the tab and never go there again...

Comment: @TheGuyOfDoom I think not even that, `cellowav.wav` is probably `undefined`

Comment: myeah, probably. I assume it'll try to use `cellowav` as an object, which it isn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `"` at the end of `innerHTML=...` in your function.

Furthermore you can't include `cellowav.wav` that way. You need to put in the url to the file there.

Should be looking something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function playSound(cellowav) {
    document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
       "<embed src=\"" + cellowav + "\" hidden=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I think `"cellowav.wav"` is meant to be `"+ cellowav +"`

Comment: @ajax333221 Thanks for the hint. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response. I actually wrote the question out wrong i have it as embed in the code. I am confused, do i not put cellowav, or cellowave.wav in the ()parameter at all, and cellowav.wav is in the root folder. I tried cellowav in the string and still nothing.

Comment: Firefox says cellowav is undifined. so how do I get the function to call a .wav file? without putting in the cellow.wav. I have looked at sites that make a sound when you rollover a link, and that is what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Rontonimo The call would be as you wrote in your question with just one change `playSound` is to be written with a capital `S` like in your function definition. If the wave file is present it should work then.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you're actually trying to do, but `cellowav.wav` doesn't need to be brought out of the string; it's a constant:

```
"<embeded src=\"cellowav.wav\" hidden=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />
```

Also, you're not closing your `<embed>` tag's string. Notice the last double quote here:

```
"<embeded src=\"cellowav.wav\" hidden=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />" // <-- Quote
```

You have also misspelled `embed`. You've written `embeded` instead.

```
"<embed src=\"cellowav.wav\" hidden=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />"
```

Comment: Thank you too for a very fast response. I just wrote embed wrong in question. cellowav.wav is in the root folder with the index.html file Thanks for the explanation on the closing parenthesis not used to the way javascript looks.